# EXCEL VBA: Compile error in hidden module only on MacOS

Tags: excel, vba, macos, macos-sierra

I have a problem with running a VBA in a Excel spreadsheet on a MacOS (Sierra). On Windows everything works like expected. I always get the "Compile error in hidden module: Interpolation ...

I tried to remove the whole content of the module and this is the leftover:

```
Function interpolate(x As Double, ran As Range) As String

interpolate1 = 1
interpolate = interpolate1

End Function
```

The VBA code is password protected and I don't use any ActiveX controls. 
The references I use are as follows:

- Visual Basic For Applications
- Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
- RefEdit Control

If anyone has any suggestions on how to go about this problem, that would be great.

Thanks,
Tro

Comment: Got it, RefEdit is missing on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

The RefEdit reference was missing on MacOS. I removed it and now it seems to work.